# Different hide transition than show transition for a view

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I get a different type of transition when hiding a view than when showing a view, even though the transition should be similar (ie if shown with slide in, the view should hide with a slide out).  The example shows a `.slide` transition.  When showing the view it slides in.  But when I hide the view it disappears immediately, it doesn't slide out.  Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?  Using Xcode 11.4.1

```
    @State var isPanelVisible = false

    var body : some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.isPanelVisible = true
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("SHOW")
                }
            }

            if isPanelVisible {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.isPanelVisible = false
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("HIDE")
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
                .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fix

```
if isPanelVisible {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.isPanelVisible = false
            }
        }) {
            Text("HIDE")
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.white)
    .zIndex(1)                   // << here !!
    .transition(.slide)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Can you explain why adding a zIndex(1) is necessary?

Comment: @andrewz, by default all views in have zIndex:0, so when one removed, the visible subviews are rendered above, hiding removing animation. Set .zIndex higher force rendering of corresponding view, and its transitions, above all others.